# Export As A Fixed Format Excel 2007

Tags: vba, pdf, excel

I have been assigned the task of developing a excel document that whole office will use. The user will click a button and the macro will export the file as a PDF to a shared folder. I wrote this code and tested this code using excel 2010. People that have excel 2007 where getting an error message saying "Run Time Error 1004 Document not saved. This document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving." I looked into the problem a little bit and found that excel 2007 needed an add-in update, so I installed it on their computers. I also checked to see if they have adobe on their computers and they do. They are still having the problem and I am unsure of what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code

```
' Define all variables
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim folder As String
    Dim member As Integer
    Dim member_count As Integer
    Dim member_name As String
    Dim show As Variant
    Dim MyTime As String

'Save as new file
        Worksheets("Input data").Visible = True
        folder = Sheets("Input data").Range("location").Value
        MyTime = Time
        Sheets("Input data").Select
        Range("G2").Value = MyTime
        strFileName = folder & "Material Request - " & Sheets("Input data").Range("name").Value & "_" & Sheets("Input data").Range("date").Value & " " & Sheets("Input data").Range("time").Value & ".pdf"
        Sheets("Material Request").Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFileName 'OpenAfterPublish:=True`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with changing the code to remove `.Select` & `.ActiveSheet` instances.

```
Dim oWS as Worksheet
Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input data")
'    Worksheets("Input data").Visible = True
    folder = oWS.Range("location").Value
    If Right(folder,1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then folder = folder & Application.PathSeparator
    MyTime = Time
'    Sheets("Input data").Select
    oWS.Range("G2").Value = MyTime
    strFileName = folder & "Material Request - " & oWS.Range("name").Value & "_" & oWS.Range("date").Value & " " & oWS.Range("time").Value & ".pdf"
Debug.Print "strFileName: " & strFileName
    'Sheets("Material Request").Select
    oWS.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFileName 'OpenAfterPublish:=True`
Set oWS = Nothing
```

Refer to this [MSDN Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238919%28v=office.12%29.aspx), you may need fill in more parameters depending on properties of the Worksheet "Input Data".

I have added some checks and refer to Immediate window to check value of `strFileName` in 2007.

Comment: Hello PatricK, Thank you for looking into my code. So I tired your modified version and I still had no luck in it working.

Comment: If it's not a full code posted, can you Step into the macro going thru the codes step-by-step by select the sub then pressing F8 in the VBEditor? Which line does it throw the error? What output you get for strFileName in Immediate window?

Comment: When I run the Macro this line, oWS.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFileName, throws the error. When I hover over xlTypePDF=0 and the strFileName is "\\FLEX_SHARED\FLEx Shared\Engineering\Materials Request\Approved

Comment: It appears that strFileName is incomplete which caused it to throw error. What value does `oWS.Range("name").Value`, `oWS.Range("date").Value` and `oWS.Range("time").Value` have? one of these should caused the strFileName to stop concatenating.

Comment: Thank you for your help PatricK I was able to find the problem! Your the best!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem (Error 1004 when attempting export). After an hour of pulling my hair out, here was the source of my problem.

I was passing a cell value as part of generating the filename. I was doing this in the format of

```
fileName:= ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & CStr(Workbooks.Cells(i,j).Value) & ".pdf"
```

The text in the cell itself was formatted to be in two rows (i.e. "top row text" + (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) + "bottom row text"). While the string looks normal in `Debug.print`, `MsgBox`, or value previews, I am thinking that there is a hidden character which encodes the new line for the cell. I believe this hidden character causes the error when passed as part of the fileName argument. I'm guessing Excel doesn't pick it up but the OS's file name system does.

In any case, this fixed the issue for me.